# How to use/set up Node Express sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been playing with Express sessions and can't get session variables to stick between routes. I made a smaller example of what I am doing. What more do I need to add to get the `req.session.user` to log true on both the `"/login"` and `"/"` endpoints? I've tried same port (no change) I've tried using `connect-sqlite3` (no change).

Backend Express server:

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(session({
    secret: "cookie",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = true
    console.log(req.session.user)
    res.status(200).json({message: "Home page", session: req.session})
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.user)
    res.status(200).json({message: "Home page", session: req.session})
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("\n *** Server live on port 3000 *** \n");
});
```

Front-end making fetch calls:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/login")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.session)
    fetch("http://localhost:3000")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.session)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

The logs for the front end and backend show:

cookie: {...}, user: true:
cookie: {...} (no user)

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Apologies I didn't think there was any sensitive data from a black background with true, and undefined showing. As for a ss of google browser errors that makes sense.

Comment: Nothing to do with "sensitive data". Look at the first bullet in the answer to that question: "Images cannot be interpreted by screen readers, making them completely inaccessible for users with visual impairments." A blind person trying to get what was printed will hear "enter image description here", not "true" or "undefined".

Comment: I gotcha makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` takes two arguments, the second of which is optional and is an object which specifies your [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#options).

One of the options is [`credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials) and by default it is set to `same-origin`.

When it is set to `same-origin`, `fetch` will **not** send cookies to cross-origin URLs and it will **not** set cookies from cross-origin URLs.

`express-session` uses cookies to track which session belongs to which browsers.

You need to change the option to `include`.

```
 fetch("http://localhost:3000", { credentials: "include" })
```

This will have the side effect of making the request [preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) and require that you [change your server-side CORS handling](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options) to allow `credentials`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. When I applied it I got the cors error "response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'." But I know my way around that error

Comment: Is there another step to saving the cookie? After fixing the cors error with
```javascript
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
    credentials: true,
}));
```
I still am getting true then undefined.